# Promise for a callback and inbound message

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a page that loads a UI library as a script tag. My page has a lib.ready() function that the library calls once it's loaded, so I'm not performing the original call, just receiving the invocation.

My page is also waiting for a message (aka event) from an external entity with the data I need to display in the UI. Sometimes the message comes before the UI is loaded and my populate routine fails.

Of course, I can't call the populate routine once the UI is ready because the message data may not have arrived.

A promise sounds like a good way to fix this but I'm not sure how to set it up when I don't invoke either of the things I'm waiting for. I've looked at creating a promise for a callback but I'm not performing that first call.

How do I structure my code to wait for the UI to load and the message to return?

```
//This is the function the UI library calls when it's loaded itself.
uilib.ready(function () {
    uilib.ui({
            view: "layout",
            rows: [tabView]    //My components to show in the UI
        });   
}

//This is a Chrome extension, waiting for a message from a web page.
//Once I get the message I populate the UI with the data.
backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    switch (message.action) {
        case WSI_SEND_RULES:
            displayRules(message.data);
            break;
    }
});

//This is how I display the data.
function displayRules(rulesTreeData) {
    clearRules();
    $$("rulesWidget").parse(rulesTreeData);  //if ui isn't loaded this fails.
}
```

Comment: It would be great if can post a template code for your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by keeping an array of the data messages received before the UI was loaded and once loaded, processed each of the waiting messages.